# Regarding Map Kit in iOS 6.0.1

Tags: iphone, dictionary, ios6, gps, xcode4.5

[image]I am not able to get my current location in iOS 6.0.1, ![Please see the screen shot when I am trying to get my current location the map view is not showing it just show blank map screen my current location latitude longitude both are correct

My code is as below:-

```
  //Start fetching logged in user current location
    self.m_LocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.m_LocationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.m_LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    self.m_LocationManager.delegate = self;

    [self.m_LocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

    self.m_LatitudeValue = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    self.m_LongitudeValue = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"lat %f long %f",self.m_LatitudeValue,self.m_LongitudeValue);
}


//for showing current location

- (void)addAnnotations { 

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.08;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.08;


    Social_Check_InAppDelegate *appDelegate = (Social_Check_InAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //user current location
        double latitudeValue = appDelegate.m_LatitudeValue;
        double longitudeValue = appDelegate.m_LongitudeValue;



    CLLocationCoordinate2D coardinate1 = {latitudeValue,longitudeValue};
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center=coardinate1;
    region.span=span;

    CSMapAnnotation *ann = [[CSMapAnnotation alloc]initWithCoordinate:coardinate1];
    ann.title = m_PlacesNameString;
    ann.type = @"green";

    [m_MapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [m_MapView regionThatFits:region];
    [m_MapView addAnnotation:ann];

    [ann release];
}
```

Above code for showing cure

Comment: you can edit the question with code :)

Answer (score 0):

this is probably because iOS 6 does not support

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

method. please check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1). Above method is deprecated. In iOS 6 and later, the location manager reports events to the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method of its delegate when they become available.

Comment: Thank you for great answer, but my problem is different now map is working fine in my project:)

Comment: ooops .. what is it now? and what was the issue earlier?